# I need to create a link URL that takes the user to the Chrome "Apps" pageI

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink, google-chrome-app

I am trying to design a Chrome app that will replace your "new tab" page. I want to create a link on the page that will take you to the "apps" page of Chrome that shows all the apps you have downloaded. I tried using:

```
<a href="chrome://apps/"><p id="apps-label"><b>Apps</b></p></a>
```

but it simply does nothing. Does anybody know a URL I can use? Or should I redirect myself using JavaScript? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening it using `chrome.tabs.create({ url: "chrome://apps"})`

However, that page is not available on Chrome OS.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I configured it so the link will open a new tab with the Chrome Apps page, and with then proceed to close the new tab page. Thank you!